# If a SoK satisfies simulatability and extractability, is this signature unforgeable and non-malleable?

Tags: signature, zero-knowledge-proofs

This paper[1] defines the *simulatability* and *extractability* of the signature of knowledge (SoK).

As is widely known, a secure signature scheme should be both unforgeable and non-malleable. Can we derive unforgeability and non-malleability from extractability? （Intuitively, non-malleability seems like it can be derived from unforgeability.）

[1] Chase, Melissa, and Anna Lysyanskaya. "On signatures of knowledge." Advances in Cryptology-CRYPTO 2006: 26th Annual International Cryptology Conference, Santa Barbara, California, USA, August 20-24, 2006. Proceedings 26. Springer Berlin Heidelberg, 2006.